# How to calculate difference of a DataTable's Column?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

If I want to perform summation, I am going ahead with:

```
private static double ColumnSummation(DataTable dt, string columnName)
{
     var sum = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<double>(columnName));
     return sum;
}
```

Now if I have to perform a subtraction of columns, how can I go ahead as there is no subtraction extension method... Is there any other way of doing so?

Please help

Comment: You can still use Sum() function, only that the other values should be negative.

Comment: You need to be clear what subtracts what (1st row subtracts all others, or all rows subtracts last row?) -- that is the reason why there is no standard SUBTRACT aggregate function.  Summing is deterministic -- just add everything -- but in subtraction the order is significant (a - b <> b - a).

Comment: @hallie, the database table is not guaranteed to enumerate in order, and LINQ's SUM is not guaranteed to call the lambda in order, so you cannot talk about a "first" row and "the others".  In general, you should not be putting lambdas with side effects into an aggregate function -- but if you need to keep track of the "first" row and "the others", you'll need to introduce such a side effect.

Answer (score 0):

If your DataTable column has 3 values say {20, 30, -10} then its sum would be 20+30-10 = 40.. But think about it, difference can only be between two values. Tell me how do you want to calculate the difference of {20, 30, -10}.. WHat do you want the result of the difference between these 3 values.. Maybe then we can try to suggest an implementation.